# Rest API PDF Document is stored as base64 and not getting opened

Tags: rest-api, pdf

I am using 3rd party document drive.  I am sending files from salesforce via rest api.  All the files are stored as base64 and not getting opened when it is downloaded.  What i am sending is as follows,

```
header:
'Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'

Body:
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"

{"indexingValues":[{"fieldName":"Doctype","values":["Test"]},{"fieldName":"DocOrigin","values":["SFDC"]}]}
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="helloworld6.pdf"
Content-Type:application/pdf

JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQ**removed base64**
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--

The document is sent to document drive&nbsp;USER_DEBUG [37]|DEBUG|System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200]
```

But the document is not getting opened.  It is always showing error, when i tried to open the document in sublime, it shows the base64 code.  Please help me.

when i tried this data in postman it is working correctly, please tell me what content type are used in post man, the generate code not generating content type for files that i have uploaded.

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try with below change Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Body"; filename="helloworld6.pdf"

Comment: I have actually figured out the issue, instead of sending the file as base64, we need to send it as text for text file, pdf object for pdf, how can we send pdf instead of base64

Comment: well you have to send base64 encoded string of pdf blob

Comment: thanks Mohith for the response.  but that was the problem.  it is stored as base64.  and the pdf is not open.  the postman is working fine.  it is sending as  ------WebKitFormBoundary3j9dEl6l5kKQq7ZH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="helloworld6.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.5
%µµµµ
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-US) /StructTreeRoot 10 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 19 0 R/ViewerPreferences 20 0 R>> how to generate pdf like this in salesforce

Comment: So you have fixed it or you still need help .If you have fixed add as an answer

Comment: Sorry mohith.  I badly need help to upload a pdf in visualforce page and send callout as pdf stream object instead of base 64.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43583/discussion-between-itsme-and-mohith-shrivastava).